# Two Identities Involving Trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $x$ by a $p \times 1$ vector and $M$, $Q$ be two $p\times p$ matrix. Then it is claimed that
$$
\mbox{trace }\left( M^{-1}xx^TM^{-1} \right) = \left\| M^{-1}x \right\|^2,
$$
and
$$
\mbox{trace }\left( M^{-1}xx^TM^{-1}QM^{-1} + M^{-1}QM^{-1}xx^TM^{-1} \right) = 2 \left( M^{-1}x \right)^TM^{-1}Q M^{-1}x.
$$
Could anyone explain how to derive these two formulas, please? Thank you!

Comment: Are either $M$ or $Q$ symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first formula, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{trace}
\tr[(M^{-1}x)(x^TM^{-1})] = 
\tr[(x^TM^{-1})(M^{-1}x)] = x^TM^{-1}M^{-1}x
$$
If $M$ is *symmetric*, we can rewrite the above as
$$
x^TM^{-1}M^{-1}x =
(M^{-1}x)^T(M^{-1}x) = \|M^{-1}x\|^2
$$
For the next part (assuming both $M$ and $Q$ are symmetric), we're meant to use the same trick:
$$
\tr \left[ 
(M^{-1}x)(x^TM^{-1}QM^{-1}) + (M^{-1}QM^{-1}x)(x^TM^{-1})
\right] =\\
\tr \left[ 
(M^{-1}x)(M^{-1}QM^{-1} x)^T + (M^{-1}QM^{-1}x)(M^{-1} x)^T
\right] =\\
(M^{-1}QM^{-1}x)^T(M^{-1}x) + (M^{-1}x)^T(M^{-1}QM^{-1}x)
$$

Comment: Darn! I was waiting for the OPs comment on if they were symmetric! Nice answer. +1

Comment: @Bey your comment gave me the idea... it seems to be the only way to make this true/easily provable